# how do I export ConEmu settings?

Tags: conemu

I'd like to export my ConEmu settings at work for use at home. I don't see any files in my AppData or Users folder that contain ConEmu settings. Is there a way to export them from within the program? I've looked and don't really see it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Latest versions has `Export` button.

[image]

[Where_settings_are_stored?](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Settings?wl=en#Where_settings_are_stored?)

Exporting settings

```
reg export HKCU\Software\ConEmu ConEmu.reg
```

Importing settings

```
reg import ConEmu.reg
```

When you are using **portable** mode, `ConEmu.xml` file may be located near to `ConEmu.exe` or `ConEmuC.exe`.

**Note** Portable mode doesn't suppose installing in `%ProgramFiles%` (x86 or x64). Obviously, ConEmu requires Write-access to `ConEmu.xml` if you want to change settings, store history, autosave windows size/pos on exit and so on. However, if you like fixed configuration and don't suppose to change xml file in any way, you may use `%ProgramFiles%`, run ConEmu first time "as Administrator", set up your configuration and Save settings (don't forget last step). After that you may run ConEmu as ordinary user with read-only access to xml-file.

Comment: Thanks. That wiki page didn't come up when I searched in google and there isn't a search for just that project on google code.

Comment: How do you import settings to a non-portable installation?

Comment: Easy. Copy `ConEmu.xml` file (name is **important**) near to `ConEmu.exe`. Run this non-portable installation with `ConEmu.xml`. Delete `ConEmu.xml` file. Open "Settings" dialog and save settings.

Comment: @Maximus: I wouldn't exactly call that "easy", and I'd definitely not call that user-friendly or obvious. You should really add an [Import] button to go along with the [Export] button.